# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

Tags: tomcat7, sqlanywhere

I'm running Tomcat 7.0.22 and I wrote a simple servlet that connects to a SQL Anywhere 12.0 database. When I run the servlet I get java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.  My ./META-INF/content.xml file looks like the following:

> ```
> <Context>
>   <Resource name="jdbc/FUDB"
>            auth="Container"
>            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
>            username="dba"
>            password="sql"
>            driverClassName="sybase.jdbc.sqlanywhere.IDriver"
>            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
> ```
>
> url="jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=dba;pwd=sql;eng=BTH476331A_FedUtilization;"
>                  accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
>                  maxActive="8"
>                  maxIdle="4" />

My webapp web.xml looks like this:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
> <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
>   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
>   version="3.0"
>   metadata-complete="true">
>     <display-name>FedUtilization</display-name>  
>     <servlet>
>   <servlet-name>Report1</servlet-name>
>       <display-name>Report1</display-name>
>       <servlet-class>com.sapgss.ps.servlet.Report1</servlet-class>
> ```
>
> Report1
>           /Report1   
>         
>           SQL Anywhere 12.0.1 server jdbc3
>           jdbc/FUDB
>           javax.sql.DataSource
>           Container

The servlet code is as follows:

> ```
> import java.io.*;
> import java.sql.*;
> import javax.servlet.*;
> import javax.servlet.http.*;
> import javax.naming.*;
> import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.*;
> import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.*;
> import com.sapgss.ps.dbutil.*;
> import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
>
> public class Report1 extends HttpServlet {
>
>     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
> ```
>
> HttpServletResponse response)
>           throws IOException, ServletException
>           {
>               try
>         {
>         response.setContentType("text/html");
>             PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
>             out.println("");
>             out.println("");
>             out.println("Hello Elaine!");
>             out.println("");
>             out.println("");
>             out.println("
>
> ## Hello Elaine!
>
> ");
>             // This is how to code access to the database in Java       Context
>   initCtx = new InitialContext();       Context envCtx = (Context)
>   initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");      DataSource ds = (DataSource)
>   envCtx.lookup("jdbc/FUDB");
>                         Connection conn = ds.getConnection();       .
>                   .
>                   .
>           }
>       }

The error happens when I try to get a DataSource at this line:
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/FUDB");

Thanks in advance I'm pulling my hair out.

Comment: I fixed this problem. What I needed to do was create a context.xml file in the %CATALINA%/localhst/webappname.xml.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I just forgot to put:

```
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
```

in my `/tomcat7/conf/context.xml`. Just added and all worked fine.

My context.xml:

```
<Context> 
    <Resource name="jdbc/gestrel" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/g...."
    username="postgres"
    password="....." maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
   maxWait="-1"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: You, sir, are my hero. This deserved a buttload of ups.

Comment: This worked for me, But I've updated factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" in server.xml instead of context.xml !

Answer (score 3):

Today I've spent a half of the day trying to deal with the similar issue. I have tomcat server.xml file defining context like this:

```
<Context docBase="app" path="/my_context_path">
</Context>
```

Then I tried to add jdbc pool support using org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.

Just added resource definition to my server.xml context definition (see above). And of cause I defined resource-ref in my web.xml.

But there was always org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource returned. I spent time debugging tomcat and finally got to the following:

1. If I define resource in server.xml context - tomcat does NOT pick that up.

   If define in web archive's META-INF/context.xml works ok.

   If define in server.xml GlobalNamingResources tag - tomcat does NOT pick that up.

   If define in tomcat global context.xml file works ok.

If you specify resource-ref in web.xml for bad cases 1,3 - tomcat will return org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource, cause as I can see it is some kind of default. BUT using such data source returned will cause something like this:


`org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)`


If not specify resource-ref in web.xml then you will get an exception telling that resource with such name could not be find.

Also I noticed that for good cases 2,4 specifying resource-ref in web.xml is not necessary (works with and without resource-ref).

Try some of the cases I described. I hope something will help.

I would try to define resource in tomcat global context.xml file.

Good luck!

P.s. I run 7.0.22 version as well.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to import javax.sql.DataSource in your servlet as you define the resouce in context.xml of  type="javax.sql.DataSource"