# Convert org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource to org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

Tags: grails, connection-pooling

Upgrading from Grails 2.2.1 to 2.4.3 everything else has upgraded fine, but having an issue with the Tomcat upgrade to 7.0.54  I am getting an error of

```
Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name
'dataSourceMBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through
constructor argument with index 0 of type
[org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: Could not convert
constructor argument value of type
[org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] to required type
[org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: Failed to convert value of
type 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource' to required type
'org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource'; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
[org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] to required type
[org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: no matching editors or
conversion strategy found
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceMBean': Unsatisfied
dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type
[org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: Could not convert
constructor argument value of type
[org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] to required type
[org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: Failed to convert value of
type 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource' to required type
'org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource'; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
[org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] to required type
[org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: no matching editors or
conversion strategy found
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:722)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.initializeContext(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:188)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The area that I am getting the error in has been around for a while

```
dataSourceMBean(com.item.management.DataSourceMBean, ref('dataSourceUnproxied'))
```

The class is:

```
class DataSourceMBean {     
   private BasicDataSource dataSource       
   public DataSourceMBean(BasicDataSource dataSource) {         
      this.dataSource = dataSource  
   }
```

When I change the dataSource to to a specific type :

```
private org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource
```

Everything compiles and all tests run fine.
Asking when did this change?
Is there an alternative to the BasicDataSource I should be using instead?

I found this article but, not sure if applies
[java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667008/java-lang-classcastexception-org-apache-tomcat-dbcp-dbcp-basicdatasource-cannot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you really need it to be a `BasicDataSource` (and I can't see why you would), don't change it to a more specific class, change it to the interface, `javax.sql.DataSource`. If you do need a particular implementation class, you can define your own `dataSource` bean by registering a `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` in `resources.groovy` and setting whatever properties are needed, e.g.

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

beans = {
   dataSourceUnproxied(BasicDataSource) {
      driverClassName = 'foo'
      username = 'bar'
      password = 'secret'
      url = 'the_url'
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

You can do this with any bean registered by Grails or a plugin as long as you use the same bean name.